# Do well to do something/ do well by doing something

Tags: prepositional-phrases, infinitive-vs-gerund

To keep your car in a good condition, you would do well __________it regularly.

1) to maintain  2) by maintaining

This question showed up on a Taiwanese senior English exam. Their answer shows that 1) is right and 2) is wrong. I don't see how 2) is wrong. If you know what is going on, please explain. Thank you.

Comment: Neither is "wrong". Did the exam ask for the _correct_ answer or the _best_ answer? There is an important difference between the two.

Comment: The examiner asked for one answer only. Anyway, let us assume he was asking for the best answer, would not 2) be the most common one?

Comment: Some older grammars may prefer the infinitive to the gerund in this construction. The infinitive is certainly better.

Answer (score 1):

The two phrasings have different meanings and are used in different contexts. Most native english-speakers would consider only the first appropriate here. Let's break it down:

#### In case [1]:

> To keep your car in a good condition, you would do well **to maintain** it regularly.

Here, 'to do well to' is a semi-colloquial expression meaning the same as, **"it is generally a good idea to"**. As such, the intent of the sentence becomes:

> "It is a good idea to maintain your car regularly," [as already stated] "to keep it in a good condition."

There are no problems with this sentence.

#### In case [2]:

> To keep your car in a good condition, you would do well **by maintaining** it regularly.

This is not correct, because 'to do well *by*' refers to something different than 'to do well *to*'.

The phrase 'to do well by *[something/someone]*' is an idiom meaning that entering into a working relationship with the object of the phrase will result in a beneficial outcome, usually material gain or generous treatment, for that person or organization.

As an example:

> The mayor **did well by** her constituents.

Meaning: 'the mayor treated her constituents well'.

Note that 'do well by' is not normally used with a gerund, and as such cannot be applied to the sentence in the exam.

.

So [1] is correct.

Incidentally, 'do well by' as an idiom is somewhat rare in modern English. The exam seems quite rigorous.